# What is this line called in MATLAB and how do I edit it?

Tags: matlab

[image]

I am referring to the **VERTICAL** line in the **SCRIPT** off to the right. I am aware of its function, but I would like to know how to edit it and what it is called. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the linebreak indicator set to 75 (since the common convention is the 80 characters due to historical terminal habits). You can set its properties in the preferences.

[image]

Comment: Thank You, just what I need, now why does it not break up copy and pastes of code? It will extend past the line and also it turns the code into a comment for some reason

Comment: @masque It doesn't break a code line as it would be super annoying if it is in the middle of a function arguments etc. It will automatically break the comment lines as a continuation since it doesn't hurt to break a comment

Comment: @masque Seems like this is the answer you were looking for. You might want to mark it as "Accepted" to let other know that this question requires no further attention. The process and purpose of accepting answers is discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

`ans` is the most recent answer, see the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ans.html). To change its value, do any operation at the command line, for example:

```
 2+2
```

will change the value of `ans` to `4`.

Comment: No sorry I should have circled it. I am speaking of the VERTICAL LINE in the SCRIPT (Yes sorry I said Workspace by accident!)